# Resize appwidget in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-2.2-froyo

Is it possible to resize appwidget in android 2.2 If yes, how?

In 3.1 we can, with property `android:resize="vertical"`, but I'm interested in 2.2

Answer (score 1):

No, it's available only from Android 3.1 .